# Combine multiple frames with widgets together in a single window with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI which basically has a single window. This window is a combination of different frames. What I want to do is to arrange these frames (Each of the frames further comprise of multiple widgets) together in a certain format:

- First frame (top left): half the size of the window from top and left
- Second frame (bottom left): half the size of the window from the bottom and left
- Third frame (top right): 1/3rd the size from the top and half the size from the right of the window.
- Forth frame (bottom right): the leftover space on the window.

Below, I have added a simple minimalistic code for the problem. To keep it simple, I have used the same FRAME class and created 4 instances of this class to be added in the main window. I use Tkinter's grid manager to organise the widgets in the frame and then again use grid manager to pack these frames into the main window.

```
import Tkinter as tk 

# Test frame class. The same frame is used to create 4 instances. 
class TestFrame(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(master)
        
        # Test Entry fields
        test_label_1                = tk.Label(master, text="Test Label 1").grid(row=0, column=0)
        test_label_1_entry          = tk.Entry(master, bd=5).grid(row=0, column=1)
        test_label_2                = tk.Label(master, text="Test Label 2").grid(row=0, column=2)
        test_label_2_entry          = tk.Entry(master, bd=5).grid(row=0, column=3)
    
        # Test checkbox fields
        test_checkbox_1_label       = tk.Label(master, text="Test check button 1").grid(row=2, column=0)
        test_checkbox_1_entry       = tk.Checkbutton(master, bd=5).grid(row=2, column=1)
        test_checkbox_2_label       = tk.Label(master, text="Test check button 2").grid(row=2, column=2)
        test_checkbox_2_entry       = tk.Checkbutton(master, bd=5).grid(row=2, column=3)
        
        # Test dropdowns
        test_dropdown_label         = tk.Label(master, text="Test dropdown 1").grid(row=3, column=0)
        list_of_options             = ["first option", "second option", "third option", "forth option"]
        first_option                = tk.StringVar(master)
        first_option.set(list_of_options[0])
        test_dropdown_label         = tk.OptionMenu(master, first_option, *list_of_options).grid(row=3, column=1)
        test_dropdown_label         = tk.Label(master, text="Test dropdown 1").grid(row=3, column=0)
        list_of_options             = ["first option", "second option", "third option", "forth option"]
        first_option                = tk.StringVar(master)
        first_option.set(list_of_options[0])
        test_dropdown_label         = tk.OptionMenu(master, first_option, *list_of_options).grid(row=3, column=1)
        pass 
    
    pass

class TestMainApplication(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(master)

        title                       = "Test Application"
        self.grid()

        # Assign the weight to each row and column as 1. This is required to align the parameters in grid.
        for r in range(3):
            self.master.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)    
        for c in range(8):
            self.master.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
        
        self.master.title(title)
        
        # Add two instances of the class TestFrame
        self.testFrame1            = TestFrame(master)
        self.testFrame2            = TestFrame(master)
        self.testFrame3            = TestFrame(master)
        self.testFrame4            = TestFrame(master)

        self.testFrame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.testFrame2.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)  
        self.testFrame3.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.testFrame4.grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=4, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)
              
        pass 
    pass 


# Main application is created here. 
root                   = tk.Tk()
mainApplication        = TestMainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I would expect after running this code, a window split into 4 parts organised in the format as discussed above. However, what I see is all the frames overlapped on top of each other.

Enviroment: MacOS, tkinter 8.6, python 3.6.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so a few problems here.

1. Your code is somewhat messy. Please consider using the PEP8 standard. [Link here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
2. If you are going to use class inherency for your frames why not do the same for your root window. I have edited your code to inherit from `Tk()`.
3. The reason for overlap is because in your `TestFrame` class you are telling your widgets they belong to `master` instead of `self` (IE the TestFrame class itself). To correct this simply replace all `master` calls in your TestFrame to `self`.
4. You use both `tk.Frame.__init__(self)` and `super().__init__(master)`. You really only need to use `super().__init__()` when using this kind of inherency.

See example code below:

```
import tkinter as tk


class TestFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        list_of_options = ["first option", "second option", "third option", "forth option"]
        first_option = tk.StringVar(self)
        first_option.set(list_of_options[0])

        tk.Label(self, text="Test Label 1").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Entry(self, bd=5).grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="Test Label 2").grid(row=0, column=2)
        tk.Entry(self, bd=5).grid(row=0, column=3)
        tk.Label(self, text="Test check button 1").grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Checkbutton(self, bd=5).grid(row=2, column=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="Test check button 2").grid(row=2, column=2)
        tk.Checkbutton(self, bd=5).grid(row=2, column=3)
        tk.Label(self, text="Test drop down 1").grid(row=3, column=0)
        tk.OptionMenu(self, first_option, *list_of_options).grid(row=3, column=1)


class TestMainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Test Application")

        for r in range(3):
            self.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        for c in range(8):
            self.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)

        self.testFrame1 = TestFrame()
        self.testFrame2 = TestFrame()
        self.testFrame3 = TestFrame()
        self.testFrame4 = TestFrame()
        self.testFrame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')
        self.testFrame2.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')
        self.testFrame3.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')
        self.testFrame4.grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=4, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')


TestMainApplication().mainloop()
```